# Leave all entries out if there is a duplicate

Tags: sql

Given the (somewhat silly) dataset of:

```
Name      Colour

Mark      Red
Mark      Yellow
Mark      Red

Sarah     Blue
Sarah     White
```

I would like to write an SQL query, that would return:

```
Sarah     Blue
Sarah     White
```

Having disregarded all "Mark" entries entirely because of the duplicate colour.
How would I facilitate this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I've tried to look out for names having duplicate colour and then ignored such names from our dataset. Assuming your table name is **table1**

```
with temp as
    (
    Select Name,colour, count(*) from table1 group by Name,colour having count(*)>1
    )
    Select * from table1 where name not in (select distinct name from temp);
```

Method 2:

```
Select * from table1 where name not in (select distinct name from (Select Name,colour, count(*) from table1 group by Name,colour having count(*)>1));
```

Comment: Interesting, thank you! Would the same result be possible without using the "with as" specifier?

Comment: I've added other query as well

Comment: Also, can you please accept my answer as well?

Comment: Thanks, method 2 is more akin to what I envisioned, though 1 is definitely more sleek.